# 500 Internal server error displaying not getting way to show error

Tags: php, hosting

I am using Godaddy windows hosting(plex) the first time for PHP. I am uploading my PHP project files on hosting to display errors I am added .user.ini and .php.ini and this file contains 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

but still not displaying error.
I am very frustrated to display error.Please help anyone.

Comment: It may because of htaccess. What kind of project do you upload on a server?

Comment: Tt is simple control/admin panel. there is no CMS is used. NO MVC is used while development.

Answer (score 1):

Open `php.ini`, You can enable display errors permanently on `php.ini`

Now scroll down through the file until you find the following line.

```
display_errors = Off
```

Once you have found the `display_errors` line replace the parameter 'Off' with 'On'. Once you have made the swap save the file and then exit the editor.

```
display_errors = On
```

**And do not forget to restart the server after changes are made.**

To enable display errors temporarily add the top of the following line of `index.php` of your application.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: I am using GoDaddy windows hosting and don't know how to restart.

Comment: Oh, that's is shared hosting you cannot restart the server then.

Comment: I am added .user.ini and .php.ini is this right or only have to add php.ini and user.ini

Comment: Check i have updated the answer, Create a new php file and add these lines top of that file and do some php syntax issues below. now run the php file if that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159977/discussion-between-thamaraiselvam-and-milind-p-chaudhari).

Answer (score 0):

We have to give permission to our directory in windows hosting.
Steps:-
1. {project directory}
2. by hovering the mouse on directory drawdown caret will appear on the right side. 
3.Click on change permission.
4. And then click on the full control. 
5. Problem solved.